# Does the "run to cursor" command skip breakpoints in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

The following description is from the book *Professional Visual Studio 2017*:

> ...while running to your cursor, a different breakpoint is hit, then
> then execution will still stop at your cursor

Does it means that the "**run to cursor**" command can skip breakpoints (not halt at the breakpoints) before reaching the cursor?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes i do,but it not skip the breakpoint.(i think it will ship,it makes confused)

Comment: So you already know the answer is "no, 'run to cursor' does not skip breakpoints".

Comment: i don't understand the mean of "while running to your cursor, a different breakpoint is hit, then execution will still stop at your cursor".

Comment: Breakpoints will never be skipped otherwise what is the point of them?

Comment: What the description means is that with `Run to cursor` a temporary break point is set at your cursor position and will be removed once it gets hit. So if you hit a break point before execution will pause and on continue you will still hit the temporary break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment: 
What the description means is that with `Run to cursor` a temporary break point (see [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#run-to-a-cursor-location)) is set at your cursor position and will be removed once it gets hit.

So, if you hit a break point before your coursor position the execution will pause (as it should on a break point). Once you continue the temporary break point (at your cursor position) will be hit.

```
1    void Example() 
2    {
3        var something = new Something(); // break point 1
4        something.OtherThing();          // cursor position
5        something.AnotherThing();       // break point 2
6    }
```

In this example if you use `Run to cursor` the break points will be hit in the following order:

- line 3
- line 4
- line 5

[Not Microsoft Source](https://dailydotnettips.com/use-run-to-cursor-and-save-time-while-debugging/)

Comment: "So if you hit a break point before execution will pause and on continue you will still hit the temporary break point" -- i got it.you means that even if hit other break point  before cursor ,continue and it will stop at cursor.

Comment: @ZhongBo exactly. I also clarified it a bit. It's basically the same as putting a normal break point there, starting to debug and removing that break point after you hit it.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Run To Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#run-to-a-cursor-location) command halts at every breakpoint.

What you are looking for is [Force Run To Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#force-run-to-a-cursor-location).

To use it, you should either:

- **Right click** on the line you want to run the code to.

[[image: Force Run To Cursor]]

Or:

- **Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>** and **click** on the symbol (to the left of the line you want to run the code to).

[image]

See also: [Debug code with force run to cursor](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debug-with-force-run-to-cursor/)